# Serverless: Lambda starts working only after a change from console/ Lambda intermittent behavior

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, serverless

I am using serverless framework for lambda deployment and I am facing this really weird problem. I use Sequelize to connect to RDS Aurora MySql DB. The deployment is successful, but when I invoke the APIs I see `SequelizeConnectionError: Connect ETIMEDOUT`. The API works fine when I run offline. But the APIs deployed don't work. They start working as soon as I make any small change on the console and save it, like changing time out from 30 to 31. But when I redeploy I face the same problem and I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Error:

```
SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Edits:

Yes. This is Aurora serverless with Data API enabled. The lambda function runs in the same VPC as the DB is in. The security group and subnets are are also same. Here is my DB config snippet:

```
DB_PORT: 3306 
DB_POOL_MAX: 10 
DB_POOL_MIN: 2 
DB_POOL_ACQUIRE: 30000 
DB_POOL_IDLE: 10000
```

This is my db.js:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    pool: {
        max: process.env.DB_POOL_MAX, 
        min: process.env.DB_POOL_MIN,
        acquire: process.env.DB_POOL_ACQUIRE,
        idle: process.env.DB_POOL_IDLE
    }
});
```

My handler file is really long with over 33 APIs. Below is one of them:

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  if (event.source === 'serverless-plugin-warmup') {
    try {
      const { Datalogger } = await connectToDatabase();
    } catch (err) { }

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
      body: 'warm-up'
    }
  }

  try {
    const { Datalogger } = await connectToDatabase();
    var datalogger;
    if (!event.headers.dsn && !event.headers.sftp)
      throw new HTTPError(404, `Datalogger serial number and SFTP root directory is mandatory`);

    datalogger = await Datalogger.findOne({
      where: {
        dsn: event.headers.dsn,
        sftpRootDir: event.headers.sftp,
      }
    })

    if (!datalogger)
      throw new HTTPError(404, `Datalogger with this input was not found`);


    console.log('datalogger', datalogger);

    await datalogger.destroy();

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
      body: JSON.stringify(datalogger)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error in destroy: ', JSON.stringify(err));

    return {
      statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
      body: err.message || 'Could not destroy the datalogger.'
    }
  }
```

I reached out to AWS support for this issue and they suspect the error has occurred due to node js version upgrade. I was previously using 8 and it was working. After upgrading to 10 its resulting in intermittent timeouts. Few calls are successful and then one failure. Now even if I go back to version 8, its same issue.

Comment: If this is Aurora Serverless, consider using the Data API. That aside, you should indicate whether or not you are running the Lambda in a VPC and provide some code showing how you are managing DB connections (or pooled connections).

Comment: @jarmod, updated post based on your comments

Comment: Take a serious look at the Data API. You don't want to manage DB connections if you can avoid it.

Comment: Yea. But that doesn't explain why the function starts working after any change from the console.

Comment: "But that doesn't explain why the function starts working after any change from the console." not many can answer the question or provide a useful comment  without ["Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm not sure what the specific answer is to your question, but I do know that once you change things in the AWS console like an environment variable or parameter, the next invocation will result in a cold start (new lambda container being created and invoked).

Locally, your function is effectively always a cold start.

This tells me that there must be some aspect of your code which prevents subsequent executions from connecting to Aurora properly.

It would help if you posted actual code, so we could offer more advice.

Comment: @AaronStuyvenberg, I have updated the post with some code if it helps. I think you are right, there is some buggy code or I missed a callback in one of the APIs and the subsequent calls are failing to connect to Aurora. I have over 33 functions and I am trying find the best way to find the issue. Thanks.